# SQL query to update database

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to update single row while I have multiple row with same Id.

I have tried update. I am expecting one sample query in that I can update single row while having multiple row on same Id.

Sample data base

```
Id | name | address 
1  |  Abc | null
1  |  Abc | null
1  |  Abc | null
```

expectation

```
Id | name | address     
1  |  Abc | xyz    
1  |  Abc | null    
1  |  Abc | null
```

Comment: It is by mistake please consider 2 and 3 as 1

Comment: Please, check this example: https://dbfiddle.uk/xulIt7OR, but also you can use `rowid` in the Oracle database.

Comment: Thankyou for you answer can you please explain with rowid

Comment: If you made a mistake in the question, click the Edit button and fix it.

Comment: Fixed..........

Comment: @DevelopWithAbhi in any way any row in the oracle database has own physical addres. This adress is named rowid. You can check it with the query: `select t.*, rowid from table t`. For each row you will see uniq address, which you can use for update statement. But be careful, because this rowid can change after modifications.

Comment: @FriendlyDragon for that very reason, because rowid is not fixed, it should not be used as an identifier outside of a single transaction. A proper data architecture would have a unique id for every row; the architecture described is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: @DevelopWithAbhi, you will want to add another column to your table that contains a unique value and declare a primary key constraint on that new column. Then you can use that value to identify specific rows. It's important to always have a way to identify specific rows in your data itself, even if it's a timestamp (log table) or a sequence-generated value. As other have pointed out, you *can* work with a table that has no identity column(s), but it becomes messy.

Comment: What if there is more records  like we have 10 I'd in database and from 10, 3 are different and we want to update 3 I'd only.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 different solutions.

**1. With rowid.**

Update randomly the first in every group by using a window function over a partition.

```
update SAMPLE_DATA_BASE up_d
set up_d.address = 'xyz'
where up_d.rowid in (select first_value(rowid) over (partition by ID)
                     from SAMPLE_DATA_BASE );
```

```
Id | name | address 
1  |  Abc | null
1  |  Abc | xyz
1  |  Abc | null
9  |  Abc | null
9  |  Abc | null
9  |  Abc | null
9  |  Abc | xyz
9  |  Abc | null
```

**2. With a new column**

```
alter table SAMPLE_DATA_BASE add (TEMP_ID number);
```

Fill the column in every row with a different number.

```
update SAMPLE_DATA_BASE set TEMP_ID = rownum;
```

Updates one of them.

```
update SAMPLE_DATA_BASE up_d
set up_d.address = 'asdw'
where TEMP_ID = 1;
```

```
Id | name | address | temp_id
1  |  Abc | null    |  8
1  |  Abc | xyz     |  6
1  |  Abc | null    |  7
9  |  Abc | null    |  4
9  |  Abc | null    |  5
9  |  Abc | asdw    |  1
9  |  Abc | xyz     |  3
9  |  Abc | null    |  2
```

```
-- clean up
alter table SAMPLE_DATA_BASE drop column TEMP_ID;
```